# Upper Bounds for Operator Norm of Block Diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices, matrix-norms

Consider the real positive definite block matrix
$$
X = \begin{bmatrix}
A &B \\ B^T &C
\end{bmatrix}
$$
with dimensions: $A$ is $d \times d$, $C$ is $k \times k$, and $B$ is $d \times k$, so $X$ is $(d+k) \times (d+k)$. Both $A$ and $C$ are positive definite as well. I am interested in upper bounds on the operator norm $\| X \| = \|X\|_2$ in terms of $A, B, C$. In particular, are there any bounds apart from the general one:

$$
\|X\| \le \|A\| + 2\|B\| + \|C\|
$$

that is described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3361631/151735)?

Comment: It can be estimated slighthly better by $\max (\|A\|,\|C\|)+\|B\|$ but there is still some space for improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the matrix $X$ is positive definite we have
$$\|X\|=\max_{\|v\|_2=1}\langle Xv,v\rangle$$
Let $v=(x,y),$ where $x\in \mathbb{R}^d,\ y\in  \mathbb{R}^k.$ Then
$$\displaylines{\langle Xv,v\rangle=\langle Ax,x\rangle +\langle Cy,y\rangle+2\langle By,x\rangle \\ \le \|A\|\,\|x\|_2^2+\|C\|\,\|y\|_2^2+2\|B\|\,\|x\|_2\|y\|_2\qquad (*)\\
\le \|A\|\,\|x\|_2^2+\|C\|\,\|y\|_2^2+\|B\|(\|x\|_2^2+\|y\|_2^2)\\ \le \left [\max(\|A\|,\|C\|)+\|B\|\right ]\,\|v\|_2^2}
$$ Hence
$$\|X\|\le \max(\|A\|,\|C\|)+\|B\|\qquad \qquad\qquad \ (**)$$
The estimate is optimal if $B=0.$

There is still some space for improvement as the quantity $(*)$ can be estimated by the norm
of $2\times 2$ matrix of the form
$$\begin{pmatrix} \|A\| & \|B\|\\ 
\|B\| &\|C\|\end{pmatrix} $$ times $\|v\|_2^2.$
In order to calculate the norm, it suffices to find the eigenvalues of this matrix and choose the one with greater absolute value.
The eigenvalues of the matrix are equal
$${\|A\|+\|C\|\over 2}\pm {1\over 2}\sqrt{(\|A\|-\|C\|)^2+4\|B\|^2}$$
so the norm of the matrix is equal
$${1\over 2}[\|A\|+\|C\|]+ {1\over 2}\sqrt{(\|A\|-\|C\|)^2+4\|B\|^2}$$
This estimate is slightly better than $(**).$

Comment: for the final result you mention, is this from the eigenvalues of the 2x2 matrix? In which case I get $0.5 [ \|A\|+\|C\| + \sqrt{(\|A\|+\|C\|)^2 - 4 ( \|A\| \|C\| - \|B\|^2)}]$. If $\|A\| \|C\| \ge  \|B\|^2 $, then the previous quantity is upper bounded by  $ 0.5 [ \|A\|+\|C\| + \sqrt{(\|A\|+\|C\|)^2}] = \|A\|+\|C\| $ if i'm not mistaken?

Comment: yeah i think that u r right since otherwise could prably also show that $\|\cdot\|_{op} $ is bounded by the mean eigenvalue wich is definitely false. In particular choosing $\|A\|=1$ and $\|B\|=\|C\|=0$ immediately shows that this cant be true.

Comment: Yes $2\times 2$ matrix. Your calculations are fine for $\|A\|\,\|C\|\ge \|B\|^2.$ But the estimate $\|A\|+\|C\|$ is far from being optimal if $\|B\|^2$ is small comparing to $\|A\|\,\|C\|.$

Comment: I have re-edited the answer  including the analysis of the norm of $2\times 2$ matrix.